# Magento 2: Get root path in url, when the domain name doesn't match with magento folder name

Tags: magento2, php, url

I have domain name for my magento 2 site something like https://abcxyz.com/index.php, and my project folder name is something like shop.xyz.com (folder name). Now I have added an external file test.php inside magento 2 folder. I want something like https://abcxyz.com/test.php.
How can I get like this in magento header phtml file ?? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Use Web Server Rewrites: YES

```
Go to System >>  Configuration >> Web >> Search Engines Optimization
```

> 2. Use secure URL Frontend: YES

```
Go to System >>  Configuration >>Web >>Secure
```

Flush the cache and check your domain is working without `index.php`

Note. Check if `.htaccess` is working or not

**Hope this solution will work for you**

Comment: Thanks, but I want to call test.php file in phtml file, can you please help me out ?

Comment: If your magento instance run without index.php then you can access test.php like this - yourdomain.com/test.php

Comment: is there a way that without removing index.php can we add test.php ??

Comment: You can create index.php instead test.php and put it in some folder name for eg.test and you can access it by domain.com/test in which test is your folder name

Comment: So if I remove index.php will domain.com/test.php work ?